# Running flutter code in the background without WorkManager

Tags: flutter, dart

I am wondering if someone managed to get such a code running in the background in Android devices without the need to use WorkManager ? I have a colleague at work who have this running smoothly in the background (on a Samsung device), but I did not manage to get it working on my Xiaomi devices. What is the catch ?

```
  _checkForNewMessages() async {
     // Do some actions ... 
    Future.delayed(Duration(minutes: 2), _checkForNewMessages);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flutter_isolate
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<int> expensiveWork(int arg) async {
  int result;
  // lots of calculations
  return result;
}

Future<int> doExpensiveWorkInBackground() async {
  return await flutterCompute(expansiveWork, arg);
}
```